# How to connect to a server if its IP address is accessed from a database

Tags: c#, database, sockets, ms-access, ip

So, I'm trying to make a chat application where when you are able to select what IP address you want to connect to. These IP addresses are stored in a database and for whatever reason when I extract the IP from a database the program doesn't connect to it, whereas when I directly give the IP in the `serverIP` variable as: `serverIP = "127.0.0.1";` it works. I have no issues extracting the IP from the database, the problem is that when you try to connect to the server with the extracted IP it fails.

This is the code I used to use to connect to a server using an IP from the database:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Address WHERE ID = 1;", conn); //query
OleDbDataReader cusReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (cusReader.Read())
{
    ip = cusReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
serverIP = ip;
cusReader.Close();

TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIP, port);
```

[image: This is the error I get]

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn how to use your debugger.  It will let you step through your code one line at a time and see the value of all the variables, etc.  This would allow you to see what is stored in the `ip` variable which would help you determine the problem.

Comment: Since you filter using a single ID, you just need to verify whether a value has beed found: `If (cusReader.HasRows) { serverIP = cusReader.GetString(0); TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIP, port); (...) }`. Your `OleDbCommand` should be declared in a `using` block.

Comment: I have updated the post, better explaining the issue. Please help.

Comment: It appears that the IpAddress you're receiving is not valid (`"0.0.0.1"`). Check your data.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that I was adding quotation marks to the IP, therefore the IP that I was accessing from the database was not the correct IP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `ip` column, then specify it in the SQL statement:

```
SELECT ip FROM Address WHERE ID = 1;
```

or explicitly look up the column by name when you read the results.  I'm not sure a `while` loop is appropriate if you are expecting at most one row.

Comment: I tried that but was greeted with the same problem. I have now added an image of the error I receive. Do you think it will provide you with more insight into this problem?